# how to implement map7 in Elm

Tags: signals, elm, map-function

I need to use do this

```
input =
Signal.sampleOn delta <|
  Signal.map7 Key
    Keyboard.arrows
    (checknumcode '1')
    (checknumcode '2')
    (checknumcode '3')
    (checknumcode '4')
    (checknumcode '5')
    delta
```

but Signal do not have map7
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just merge some of the signal and use map3

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the 2.1.0 version of the core package, you could use the Fancy Mapping (<~) and (~) operators that you find in the [Signal package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Signal). From version 3.0 these functions are not in the core anymore, you can find them in the [Signal Extra package](https://github.com/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra)

You could find [here](http://elm-by-example.org/chapter3mousesignals.html) another explanation on how to use these operators

Your function would become something like

```
Key <~ Keyboard.arrows
    ~ (checknumcode '1')
    ~ (checknumcode '2')
    ~ (checknumcode '3')
    ~ (checknumcode '4')
    ~ (checknumcode '5')
    ~ delta
```

Comment: fancy map is not in core 3.0 anymore

Comment: You can use the elm-signal-extra package if you decide you want them https://github.com/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra